# Cannot install QuickCheck for Haskell: "runInteractiveProcess: permission denied"

Tags: powershell, haskell, cabal, quickcheck

When I run the commands

```
cabal update

cabal install QuickCheck
```

on windows powershell, or

```
 cabal install --lib --package-env . QuickCheck
```

I get runInteractiveProcess: permission denied. I have found that I need to run "/scripts/securetmp" and un-secure my /tmp. How do I do that? What does it mean to run /scripts/securetmp?
I was asked for the link to the advice, here are 2 links from 2 different people who said the same:
1.In one of the answers on a similar question on StackOverflow:
[Can't install and use Cabal (Haskell) on CentOS Server - zlib-0.5.4.1 failed during the building phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461456/cant-install-and-use-cabal-haskell-on-centos-server-zlib-0-5-4-1-failed-dur)
2.On a website, though it's in Russian, but says the same thing:
https://coderoad.ru/24461456/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-Cabal-Haskell-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-CentOS-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0

On both those links there are other answers, that talk about running some bootstrap.sh script. That might be another solution, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: hi, please could you add the link to the source of the advice to get more details?

Comment: I added the links.

Comment: The answers in other StackOverflow answer apply to Linux installation and I'm assuming you are using windows. Trying to reproduce your error, unfortunately, installed QuickCheck successfully without any errors(ghc -V -> 8.6.5, cabal -V -> 2.4.1.0) . Out of interest,  what cabal version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it using :`cabal --http-transport=plain-http install QuickCheck`, with this you will be forcing cabal not to use powershell's webclient, it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, it still says "permission denied"